# Configuring url IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

I'm configuring an IIS 8 Server, and here is the schema that I'm thinking.

I need two environments

- Homolog, is the first and will be a server for applications homologation. Runs at port 8585.
- Production, is the production site, and applications running here will be configured under a DNS, and a specific domain. Runs ant port 8080.

Inside ineptup/wwwroot folders I have this structure

[image]

I want to access applications under homolog's environment with:

- Http://< ip address >:< port >/homolog/< appName >

I want to access applications under production's environment with:

- http://< ip address >:< port >/production/< appName >
- mydomain.net

So, how can I configure it at IIS 8?

Answer (score 0):

Normally IIS Default Website(which is pointed to inetpub folder) will run on 80 port, You can override it.

If you want to have different ports for your sites
Create website by right clicking on sites, give appropriate path and port number in below window

Give site name(this can be any name just to identify your site in IIS)
Physical path
Port Number
While creating sites check the application pool, it should target to your framework

For domain you have to give host name, before that you have to map your server with DNS provider

[image]

[This link](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site) will guide you through the steps